# sudo: port: command not found setting up Ruby with MySQL MAMP

Tags: ruby, mamp

I'm using a Mac 10.6.6, with MAMP installed. I am trying to get Ruby working. There is a problem with the headers, so I was referred to this tutorial. http://blog.mirotin.net/?p=35

I have MySQL 5.5. installed on my computer

When I type in the 5th line below `$ sudo port install cmake`, it says

```
sudo: port: command not found
```

Do you know what I can do about this?

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mv /Users/yourname/Desktop/mysql-5.5.9.tar.gz .
$ tar xf mysql-5.5.9.tar.gz
$ cd mysql-5.5.9
$ sudo port install cmake
$ cmake . -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Applications/MAMP/Library
$ make -j 3
$ cp libmysql/*.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
$ mkdir -p /Applications/MAMP/Library/include/mysql
$ cp include/* /Applications/MAMP/Library/include/mysql
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /tmp/mysql-5.5.9/libmysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
$ rm -rf /tmp/mysql-5.5.9 /tmp/mysql-5.5.9.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

It would me much better if you keep the posts in the same thread. Therefore we can help you more easily by reading the problem from the start.

port is an OS X package manager known is MacPorts. Therefore to get it to work you must first install MacPorts from http://www.macports.org/.